# What's the 'magic' of 509 files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I make array of 550 (or more) objects (which contain ofstreams), first **509** objects are 'good' ones (with files etc.), but further objects are 'wrong'. 

Have no clue what I made wrong.

Maybe special initialization of ofstream is needed?

This issue is for both 'Debug' and 'Release' versions.

Code (C++) (compiled under Microsoft Visual C++ 2012):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class C {
    int n;
    ofstream f;
public:
    C() {n=1;}
    void Bind(char* filename);
};

void C::Bind(char* filename) {
    f.open(filename,ios::binary);
    if (!f)  cout << "file " << filename << " Error..." << endl;
}

int main() {
    C *c = new C[550];
    for (int i=0;i<550;i++) {
        char filename[256];
        sprintf_s(filename, "file-%03d.bin", i);
        c[i].Bind(filename);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> file file-509.bin Error...
>   file file-510.bin Error...
>   file file-511.bin Error...
>   file file-512.bin Error...
>   file file-513.bin Error...
>   ... ... ...

What's the magic of these 509 files? 

How should I correct this code for array with 550 (or more) objects?

Thank you!

Comment: A well placed `perror` may help you here. Probably ran out of file handles. Windows should allow millions of handles, but the C runtime may be capped at 512 or similar number.

Comment: Note that the best solution is probably to change your design so that you don't open so many files at once.

Comment: @user4581301, thank you, so I can freely change conception from ofstream to HANDLE (with CreateFile(...), WriteFile(...) etc.)?

Comment: Give the suggestions in the linked duplicate a try before using `CreateFile` you may find yourself opening yourself up to a whole new set of problems.

Comment: @interjay, thank you for helpful link; the _setmaxstdio(1000) can help for quick fix; and I'll think about redesign for future.